# MySQL Workbench mysqldump: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces

Tags: mysqldump, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

When using workbench on Mysql 8, I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces
```

I'm aware of `Bug #30350829` in the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-21.html#mysqld-8-0-21-security)

It seems `--no-tablespaces` needs to be added.

How do you add `--no-tablespaces` when using the export tool in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @ErgestBasha running mysqldump command line with `--no-tablespaces` works, but how do you add this to the mysqldump command used in MySQL Workbench export tool? I don't see an option to add it.

Answer (score 1):

(Workaround using command line in Microsoft Windows)

In MysqlWorkbench, rightclick on your database connection, click "Edit connection...", memorize your hostname, port, username, password.

Open a cmd.exe

Go in MySQL Workbench folder:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE"
```

Run mysqldump.exe:

```
mysqldump.exe --all-databases --host=YOUR_HOSTNAME --port=YOUR_PORT --default-character-set=utf8 --user=YOUR_USER --password=YOUR_PASSWORD --protocol=tcp --single-transaction=TRUE --column-statistics=0 --no-tablespaces > my_dump.sql
```

Of course don't use your password in command line like this, since it's insecure.